# error: cannot find symbol input.nextdouble

Tags: java

Cant figure out why I keep getting this error. I'm trying to write a program that will add the sum of a 2 digit number.

```
SplitNum.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
double digit = input.nextdouble();
                ^
  symbol:   method nextdouble()
  location: variable input of type Scanner
1 error
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SplitNum
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 2 digit number");
        double digit = input.nextdouble();
        double tens = digit / 10.0;
        double ones = digit % 10.0;
        double sum = tens+ones;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: It's `input.nextDouble()`

Comment: awhhh thanks appreciate it

Comment: Also note for the future that Java and Javascript are entirely different languages.

Comment: Please accept an answer if they worked for you by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method name 
`nextdouble()` to

**nextDouble()**

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be [`input.nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) instead of `input.nextdouble()`

In Java, coding conventions say that for method names, the first letter of every word, excluding the first one, must be capitalized.